# Three-dimensional array traversal

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, operating-system

I come across a problem about three-dimensional array and I cannot figure it out.Assume that I am using C++ and I have a three-dimensional array a[i][j][k]. There are six ways with different orders of traversing it:

> i-j-k, i-k-j, j-i-k, j-k-i, k-i-j, k-j-i

Now I try to compare the running time of different ways. I use g++ -O0 on Windows and my code are as follows:

```
#define N 512
#include<ctime>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[N][N][N],b[N][N][N],c[N][N][N];
int main(){
    clock_t start;
    clock_t finish;
    start=clock();
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
            for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
                c[i][j][k]=a[i][j][k]+b[i][j][k];
    finish=clock();
    cout<<finish-start<<"ms ";
    start=clock();
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
                c[i][j][k]=a[i][j][k]+b[i][j][k];
    finish=clock();
    cout<<finish-start<<"ms ";
    start=clock();
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
                c[i][j][k]=a[i][j][k]+b[i][j][k];
    finish=clock();
    cout<<finish-start<<"ms ";
    start=clock();
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                c[i][j][k]=a[i][j][k]+b[i][j][k];
    finish=clock();
    cout<<finish-start<<"ms ";
    start=clock();
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
                c[i][j][k]=a[i][j][k]+b[i][j][k];
    finish=clock();
    cout<<finish-start<<"ms ";  
        start=clock();
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                c[i][j][k]=a[i][j][k]+b[i][j][k];
    finish=clock();
    cout<<finish-start<<"ms ";
    return 0;
}
```

I think the running time of the order i-j-k will be the shortest since the memory space it visits is always continuous. However it comes out that j-i-k is even faster. The output is something like this:

> 656ms 1817ms 310ms 8475ms 5820ms 11804ms

I run this program several times, the running time varies a bit but the order remains the same. When I run this program on Ubuntu, i-j-k becomes the fastest, which makes me rather confused. I want to know why this program behaves like this on Windows, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add the timing info for the various tests. That will be useful to those that are able to respond to your question.

Comment: Also try to change test order

Comment: @MBo I have tried to change the order. As long as I don't test j-i-k in the first place, it will be the fastest. If I test j-i-k in the first place, it's a little slower than i-j-k. But that doesn't explain why j-i-k is so fast(always faster than i-k-j whichever the order is, at least).

Comment: It's all about caching and virtual memory. Going beyond that requires a lot of details about the machines that you're running on, and the internals of the OS. The one thing that's pretty predictable is that "k last" will be fastest on any machine that has a cache.

Comment: Scanning right dimension last should be faster, so both` i-j-k` and `j-i-k` orders are the fastest, it is normal.

Comment: @MBo Sorry, my mistake. So the difference is all about traversing order?

Comment: @user3386109  I understand. That explains why the case tested first runs a little slower. If I run j-i-k first it won't be the fastest. Thanks a lot : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all one should know how memory is allocated to multi-dimension array. [here](https://dzone.com/articles/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-1) is very detailed explanation is given how array gets memory allocation.
For N dimension array visualization and working [This](https://www.quora.com/How-is-a-3-dimensional-array-stored-in-the-memory-What-about-arrays-with-n-dimensions-How-do-I-visualize-them-How-do-I-work-with-them) is very good page you can get.
This will completely solve your problem. BTW I also going to read those pages :0

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in ubuntu 14.04. I got the shorted running time from order i-j-k. [Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmNRS.jpg)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what do you think of the results on different OS?